# insert text from textbox into MS access database(into cells)

Tags: vb.net

is anyone here who tried something like that before? I tried to insert text from textbox into acces database, but I don't know what should i use instead of  "?".

Here is code:

```
  provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="  
  datafile = "F:\Test Database\Database.accdb"   
  conString = provider & datafile
  myConnection.ConnectionString = conString
  myConnection.Open()

    Dim str As String
    str = "Insert into TABLA([LABELS]) Values (?)"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    'cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Panel", CType(Textbox1.Text, String)))
    Select Case panelCount
        Case 1
            cmd.Parameters.Add("LABELS", CType(TextBox1.Text, String)).Value = "?".Rows(0).Cells(1).Value.ToString()
        Case 2
               cmd.Parameters.Add("LABELS", CType(TextBox1.Text, String)).Value = "?".Rows(0).Cells(2).Value.ToString()
    
       End Select
    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        myConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    myConnection.Close()
```

Thank you in advance for your help

What is difference between "ITEM" and CELLS" and which should i use?)

Comment: Simple google search would give you probably millions of howto's and tutorials on exactly this

Comment: If your data is stored in a textbox you simply use the TextBox.Text property (where TextBox should be replaced by your textbox variable name). By the way. Use OleDbType.VarWChar for the parameter type

Comment: @Hursey Thank you man, but i am not professional like you and i don't understand everything. If your method: simple browsing have works, i wouln't type these question. I thought if anyon doesn't understand something, he type his question here, but but your approach will not help anyone.

Comment: No, actually my approach will help you more than you think.  If some one was to just type this all out for you and give you the answer for you to copy and paste, you will have exactly zero understanding of how it works.  I would also suggest, this is the most elementary part of vb.net database development so would be worth you taking some time to do the research so you have complete understanding and are able to scale up your abilities

Comment: You're right, I won't understand it by copying. I asked this question because I didn't find the answer or how to tutorial on Google. Remember that you were also a beginner and you were also frustrated that you could not solve all the problems yourself. 
I think people turn to forums when they can't find / understand google guides, so the answer google it is not on right place here.

Comment: Google "vb.net tutorial access database"  Gave heaps of suggestions and while I understand not any one of them will give you the Exact answer you're looking form, they will get you heading in the right direction.  https://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets12p4.html seems a good place to start

Answer (score 1):

Declare and dispose of your database objects (connections and commands etc.) in the method where they are used. I am glad that you are calling `.Dispose` but the framework languages provide `Using...End Using` blocks to accomplish this even if there is an error.

Don't open the connection until directly before the .Execute....

I was happy to see the use of parameters but your implementation seemed a bit confused.

Don't show a message box while the connection is open. If all you want to do is show a message box on error that is really part of the user interface code so, your Try Catch would be better there.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim valueToInsert As String = ""
    Select Case panelCount 'I assume this is a Form level variable
        Case 1
            valueToInsert = "Some value" 'I didn't get where your values were coming from
        Case 2
            valueToInsert = "Some other value"
        Case Else
            valueToInsert = "A default value"
    End Select
    Try
        InsertDatabase(valueToInsert)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub InsertDatabase(labelValue As String)
    Using myConnection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\Test Database\Database.accdb"),
            cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Insert into TABLA([LABELS]) Values (?)", myConnection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("Label", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = labelValue
        myConnection.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, you have helped me several times and I am incredibly grateful to you

Comment: @Lasicak You are very welcome. The best way to thank someone on Stack Overflow is by accepting their answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.